# How to save the picture take by xamarin media plugin to the localhost xampp?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xampp

I have connect my phone to my localhost(xampp) but i fail to save the picture take by xamarin plugin to my pc directory. Below is my code:

```
 public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //CameraButton.Clicked += CameraButton_Clicked;
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
        request.RequestUri = new Uri("http://192.168.137.1/pic/");
        request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
        request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        //var client = new HttpClient();
        //HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request);

    }
```

Below is save photo code:

```
 var file = CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
                {                    
                    DefaultCamera = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.CameraDevice.Rear,
                    CompressionQuality = 92,
                    SaveToAlbum = false,
                    Directory= "http://192.168.137.1/pic/",
                    Name = DateTime.Now + "_test.jpg"
                });
```

Can anyone share me idea how to make it done? Please help and thanks.

Comment: CrossMedia isn't going to magically upload the image to a server for you.  You need to save the file locally first (or use the image stream) and then use that data to transfer via a webservice to your server